# Put request with file and json leads to "Stream consumed" error

Tags: python, fastapi, endpoint, starlette

I'm writing FastAPI endpoint with **file** and **json** as arguments. Block below demonstates a part of a fastapi endpoint:

```
@app.put(f"{settings.API_PREFIX}" + "/project")
async def set_project(request: Request, file: Optional[UploadFile] = File(None)):
    authorization: str = request.headers.get('Authorization')
    content_type: str = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    request_json = await request.json()
```

I'm trying to make a request with the following code:

```
def test_put_project(self):
    files = [('file', open(r'filepath', 'rb'))]
    json = {'uuid': "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            'name': "",
            'meta': "",
            'type': '',
            'path': '',
            'flags': 1,
            }
    resp = requests.put(url=self.url,
                        headers={"Authorization": TOKEN},
                        files=files,
                        json=json
                        )
```

at the line `request_json = await request.json()` the endpoint fails with the following error:
`venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\starlette\\requests.py\", line 218, in stream\n    raise RuntimeError(\"Stream consumed\")\nRuntimeError: Stream consumed\n"`

I'm expecting that my enpoint correctly handles both: json and file data.

Comment: The second paragraph of this [issue comment](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/issues/1675#issuecomment-1675287630) explains very well why this happens. You have to check for instances of `starlette.exceptions.HTTPException` and check if the request was disconnected. `await request.is_disconnected()`

Comment: You can't combine a JSON body with a UploadFile (which is a different encoding). In either case, it will depend on whether you have a middleware active as well (which is what the issue linked to is about). There is no `json()` to return when the request a form-encoded one.